# MIPS Assembler Read String overrides Print String

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

```
.text
la $t5, prompt
la $t6, prompt_char
la $t7, prompt_loop

loop:
la $t4, 0 #count


askForString:
la $a0, prompt
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0,8
li $a1, 5 #text einlesen
syscall

j quit

quit:
la $a0, ($t7)
li $v0, 4   #info
syscall

li $a1, 5 #text einlesen
li $v0,5
syscall

beq $v0,1,askForString

exit:

.data
prompt: .asciiz "\nPlease enter text\n"
prompt_char: .asciiz "\njetzt bitte ein Zeichen\n"
prompt_loop: .asciiz "\nAgain: 1, Exit: 0.\n"
endl: .asciiz "\n\n"
```

The problem if i continue the loop my text stored in "prompt"(syscall 4) will be overridden by the input(syscall 5).
do i need to clean $a0 or what is the problem. please help

My Result:

> Please enter text
>
> aa
>
> Again: 1, Exit: 0.
>
> 1
>
> aa (here should be "Please enter text")
>
> 1
>
> Again: 1, Exit: 0.
>
> 1
>
> 1 (here should be "Please enter text")
>
> 0
>
> Again: 1, Exit: 0.
>
> 0
>
> -- program is finished running (dropped off bottom) --

Comment: As [the documentation](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html) states, system call 8 will store the input at the address contained in `$a0`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a new memory location for your input string:

```
.text
la $t5, prompt
la $t6, prompt_char
la $t7, prompt_loop

loop:
la $t4, 0 #count


askForString:
la $a0, prompt
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0,8
la $a0, input  #### --> Other address here
li $a1, 5 #text einlesen
syscall

j quit

quit:
la $a0, ($t7)
li $v0, 4   #info
syscall

li $a1, 5 #text einlesen
li $v0,5
syscall

beq $v0,1,askForString

exit:

.data
prompt: .asciiz "\nPlease enter text\n"
prompt_char: .asciiz "\njetzt bitte ein Zeichen\n"
prompt_loop: .asciiz "\nAgain: 1, Exit: 0.\n"
endl: .asciiz "\n\n"
input: .space 128  ### --> Some space to put the input
```